# Deriving Lorentz-covariant expression for the retarded Green's function of wave equation in $n+1$ dimensions

Tags: special-relativity, waves, mathematical-physics, greens-functions, propagator

Consider spacetime to be homogeneous and isotropic. Then, the Green's function for the wave equation satisfies
\begin{equation}
\square G(x^{\mu}) = \delta^{n+1}(x^{\mu}).\tag{1}
\end{equation}

In $3+1$ dimensions, this can be solved to get the retarded Green's function
\begin{equation}
G(x^{\mu}) = \frac{\delta(t-r)}{4\pi r},\tag{2}
\end{equation}
or, in a covariant form,
\begin{equation}
G(x^{\mu}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \theta(t)\delta(x^{\mu}x_{\mu}).\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Can we get a similar covariant expression in $n+1$ dimensions? If so, how do we go about doing it?

Comment: Since this is link-only, it is nor an answer, but you might be interested in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02903572). It does not make the calculation you wan, but it gives the general steps and shows how one can use the result in $d$ dimensions to obtain the result in $d+2$ dimensions. It should be mentioned that the expressions tend to be considerably different in $d\neq 3+1$ (and are particularly nasty in odd-dimensional spacetimes)

Comment: Unfortunately, I was looking if there was an explicit covariant expression for the Green's function, while this paper both leaves it as a recurrence relation, and the covariance is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a recursion formula
$$G_{d+2}(r^2,t)~=~-\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\partial G_d(r^2,t)}{\partial (r^2)}, \qquad d~\geq~2,\tag{29'} $$
which preserves the covariant structure, cf. Ref. 1. The first few read
$$G_1(t)~=~\theta(t)t~=~\max(t,0),$$
$$G_2(r^2,t)~=~\frac{1}{2}\theta(t)\theta(t^2-r^2)\tag{31'}$$
$$G_3(r^2,t)~=~\frac{\theta(t)\theta(t^2-r^2)}{2\pi\sqrt{|t^2-r^2|}}+\text{sing. terms}\tag{31"} $$
So e.g. combining eqs. (29') & (31') leads to OP's covariant eq. (3).

In eq. (31") the singular terms [which appear in odd spacetime dimension $d$] have support on the [light-cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) $\{(\vec{r},t)\in\mathbb{R}^d | r^2=t^2\}$. This is related to failure of [Huygens' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle#In_other_spatial_dimensions), cf. e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129324/2451) Phys.SE post and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8794/11127) Math.SE post.

The singular terms require care to be mathematically well-defined. For more details, see e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3908388/11127).

References:

1. H. Soodak & M.S. Tiersten, *Wakes and waves in $N$ dimensions,* [Am. J. Phys. 61 (1993) 395](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17230).