# Inhomogeneous Solution to 2+1D wave-equation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, waves, greens-functions

The inhomogeneous wave equation
$$\left(\frac{1}{c^2} \partial_t^2 - \Delta\right)G(\vec{r},t)=\delta^3(\vec{r})\delta(t) \tag{0}$$
for a point-source in three spatial dimensions can be tackled by means of the Fourier-space, that is writing
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4} \int {\rm d}^3k \int {\rm d}\omega \, \tilde{G}(\vec{k},\omega) \, e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}-i\omega t} \\
\delta(\vec{r})\delta(t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int  {\rm d}^3k \int {\rm d}\omega \, e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}-i\omega t} $$
and plugging these into (0), which gives
$$\left(k^2-\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\right)\tilde{G}=1$$
and so $$\tilde{G}=\frac{1}{k^2-\omega^2/c^2} + a_1(\vec{k}) \delta(k-\omega/c) + a_2(\vec{k})\delta(k+\omega/c)$$
with arbitrary functions $a_1$ and $a_2$. These terms actually only give the homogenous solution. The first term is responsible for the inhomogeneity. Then,
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{c^2}{(2\pi)^4} \int {\rm d}^3k \int {\rm d}\omega \, \frac{1}{k^2c^2-\omega^2} \, e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}-i\omega t} \tag{1} \, .$$

For $t>0$, the $\omega$-integral, can be calculated by closing the contour in the lower-half complex plane. A physical causality argument then justifies pushing the poles at $\omega=\pm kc$ in the lower-half complex plane and the residue-theorem then gives
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{-ic}{16\pi^3} \int \frac{{\rm d}^3k}{k} \, e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}} \left( e^{ikct} - e^{-ikct} \right) \, . \tag{2}$$
Evaluating this remaining integral is most easily done in 3d-spherical coordinates with the result
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{1}{4\pi r} \, \delta(t-r/c) \,. \tag{3}$$
The result has the interpretation, that an instantaneous perturbation at $t=0$ and $\vec{r}=0$, will only have an effect at $r$ after the retarded time $r/c$.

My question is now with regard to the version in 2+1D. The analysis above holds, except (2) becomes
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{-ic}{8\pi^2} \int \frac{{\rm d}^2k}{k} \, e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}} \left( e^{ikct} - e^{-ikct} \right) \, . \tag{4}$$

With polar-coordinates (4) becomes
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{-ic}{8\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}\varphi \int_0^\infty {\rm d}k \, e^{ikr\cos\varphi} \left( e^{ikct} - e^{-ikct} \right) \, . $$
where wlog $\vec{r}=r \vec{e}_x$ was assumed. The $k$-integral does not converge, but can be continued analytically by introducing a dampening factor $e^{-ks}$ and taking the limit $s\to 0^+$ with the result
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{c}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}\varphi  \, \frac{ct}{c^2t^2-r^2\cos^2t}. $$
If $r>ct$, then the integral is only defined as a principal value and becomes $0$. It is only non-zero for $r<ct$ and can be done via the residue theorem
$$G(\vec{r},t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\Theta(ct-r)}{\sqrt{t^2-r^2/c^2}} \, . \tag{5}$$
The fact that $r<ct$ is causally plausible, since an instantaneous perturbation at $t=0$ and $\vec{r}=0$ can not have an effect at $r$ if $ct<r$ i.e. the wave hasn't had the time to travel the distance. But contrary to the 3+1D case, the Greens function in the 2+1D case does not appear to exhibit a sharp response i.e. the instantaneous perturbation at $t=0$ and $\vec{r}=0$ does only act at distance $r$ after the the time $r/c$, but the same position at distance $r$ will be affected at later times as well, after the pulse should have passed already.

Is there a mathematical error, or what is the interpration to this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701573/2451

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. Your result is given in Jackson's, Classical Electrodynamics as problem 6.1. Physically, you can imagine that the 2-d source is a line source in 3-d. The radiation from the closest point is the initial effect, and radiation from the rest of the long line source takes longer to get to your observation point. Jackson calls this a "wake".

Comment: Ah, thanks. This makes sense :-) But what if my problem physically only lives in 2d and there is no line source in 3d. The solution appears to know, that there are 3 dimensions in this world, not just 2. I mean, otherwise the same argument could be then further pushed to the 3d case, in that there is something in 4d that makes it look as is it, right?

Comment: You can calculate the 3d Green's function by integrating the 4d one. The Green's function in 1d and 2d usually don't describe the physical source that you are thinking about. That is, for example, for a 1d equation describing a string which microscopically might be considered to consist of masses joined by springs, You might tap a mass giving it an impulse, which corresponds to a delta function in space and time force. This will correspond to a derivative of a delta function source, and when substituted into the Green's function equation solution the correct propagating pulse.

Comment: Not sure I follow your scenario.For a linear chain of springs with masses at $\mathbb{Z}$ you want to apply a force to the mass at $0$ i.e. $F=\delta(x)\delta(t)$, so at $x=0$ the action of the force results in a net momentum of $1$.From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867619/how-to-make-sense-of-the-greens-function-of-the-41d-wave-equation/3908388#3908388 the Greensfunction in $1+1$ dimensions is $$G_{\rm ret}=\frac12\Theta(t-x)\Theta(t)$$ that is, the action at $x=0,t=0$ results in a constant action at $x$ for all $t>x>0$. Why is the delta function force the derivative of a delta?

Comment: Yes that example is probably not the appropriate one and you should ignore it. That is the correct Green's function, and you can use it to solve problems for wave guides and transmission lines, etc. in the usual way.